# Maven : Filtering any ressources

Tags: java, maven, jsp

I want to filtering two `jsp` in my project

***header_connect.jsp:***

```
...
<bean:message key="version"/>&nbsp;<bean:message key="${numeroVersion}"/>
...
```

i have properties files dependent on the current profile
***Example filter-dev.properties:***

```
mode=- Developpements
numeroVersion=numero.version.livraison.dev
```

***my pom.xml:***

```
<!-- Profiles -->

<properties>
    <jspFolder>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/generic/tiles/</jspFolder>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <profileVersion>DEV</profileVersion>
            <webXmlfolder>dev</webXmlfolder>
            <mode>- Developpements</mode>
            <filterFile>src/main/filters/filter-dev.properties</filterFile>
            <configFolder>src/main/config/dev/</configFolder>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    ...
</profiles>

<!-- FIN Profiles -->

<build>
    <finalName>${applicationShortname}_${majorVersion}_${minorVersion}_${profileVersion}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
                    <filter>${filterFile}</filter>
                </filters>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                <webResources>
                    ...
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${jspFolder}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>header_connected.jsp</include>
                            <include>template_blank.jsp</include>
                        </includes>
                        <targetPath>/WEB-INF/jsp/generic/tiles/</targetPath>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
            ...
        </plugin>
```

When i do this my `jsp` is not filtering

Comment: Hmm reading like this, I'm not seeing any errors. Can you try to reduce the amount of code and come up with a simple example, a [mcve]?

Comment: @Tunaki i have edit my post

Comment: Yes, but by reduce, I meant simplifying your project, a lot. By removing all that is not necessary here so we can focus on the real problem.

Comment: @Tunaki i don't understand, i reduce code to focus the problem in this case